# How to get url of navigated page after button click using WebBrowser Control in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm successfully navigating from www.url**1**.com to www.url**2**.com using webbrowser control but iam unable to get the url of navigated page i.e., www.url**2**.com, using Webbrowser control in asp.net web application.

If you have any solution regarding this issue please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `webbrowser control`?

Comment: Webbrowser is used to crawl the any website(url)

Answer (score 0):

```
String Path = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri).OriginalString;
String rootDirectory = Path.Substring(0, LastIndexOf("/"));
```

Comment: what you have posted is for getting localhost url, but I required url captured by WEBBROWSER control.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is to navigate the WebBrowser control to a specific URL

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. OP wants to get the URL of the page navigated to. not how to navigate.

Comment: Go Through this Link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/webbrowser-control-in-C-Sharp-and-windows-forms/

Comment: That link won't help me